# Bayesian estimation of nonlinear state space model using Gibbs Sampler

Tags: bayesian, markov-chain-montecarlo, state-space-models

I want to estimate a state space model that looks like this:

$y_t = exp(\beta_t)x_t + \varepsilon_t \hspace{1cm} \varepsilon_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_{\varepsilon})$

$\beta_t = \rho\beta_{t-1}  + \nu_t \hspace{1cm}  \nu_t \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2_{\nu})$

where $y_t$ and $x_t$ are observed, while $\beta_t$ is the unobserved latent state. How can I estimate this model using Bayesian methods? Do I need a Metropolis step or particle filter step in the Gibbs sampler to estimate the model?

Is there any approximation or another approach that allows me to rewrite the state space as a linear system and use the Kalman filter/smoother inside the Gibbs Sampler?